# what is happening when try to use array variable

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[]=new int[2];
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

This an example. Can anybody explain this.

Comment: What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: What did happen when you ran the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// declares an array of integers
int[] anArray;

// allocates memory for 10 integers
anArray = new int[10];

//declares an array of integers and allocates memory for 2 integers
int array[]=new int[2];
```

And if you want to print that thing use [--> this <--](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/4088809)

```
//print the content of the array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Because this :

```
System.out.println(array);
```

is not going to print the content of your array, it will print the memory address of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You just defined the array and java by default initialized that array context i.e. array[0] and array[1] with default value i.e. 0.

When you will print the array it will just print the type of Array i.e. Int array followed by hashCode something like I@32324.